# TreeViewの初期化のsetRoot()でコンパイルエラーになってしまう

Tags: java, javafx

JavaFXの問題というよりジェネリックの使い方の問題なのかもしれませんが、エラーの解決方法がわかりません．すみませんがご教示お願いいたします．

### 背景

JavaFXを使用してデスクトップアプリを作ろうとしています．TreeViewを表示させたいのですが、初期化の箇所でコンパイルエラーになってしまいます．

**開発環境**
jdk 17.0.1
JavaFx 17.0.2
Eclipse 2021-12

### エラーメッセージ

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method setRoot(TreeItem<TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree>>) 
in the type TreeView<TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree>> 
is not applicable for the arguments (TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree>)  
OtMainController.java   /OtInvoker/src/com/xxx/ditaot/app   line 88 Java Problem
```

### コード

#### FXML

OtMain.fxml（TreeView該当箇所）

```xml
    <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="%tabTxtDitaOt">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="346.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                 <children>
                     <TreeView prefHeight="346.0" prefWidth="200.0" fx:id="tvDitaOt"/>
                 </children></AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
```

#### コントローラ

OtMainController.java（関係ないコードもあると思います）

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import com.xxx.ditaot.util.XmlResourceBundle;
import com.xxx.ditaot.util.XmlResourceBundleControl;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

//...
public class OtMainController  extends Application implements Initializable{
    private static final String RESOURCE_BUNDLE_PATH = "." + File.separator + "resource" + File.separator + "property";
    private static final String ICON_FILE_PATH = "." + File.separator + "resource" + File.separator + "icon";
    private static final String DITAOT_ROOT_ICON = "icons8-home-48.png";
    private static final String DITAOT_ICON = "icons8-folder-48.png";
    private static final String DITAOT_PLUGIN_ICON = "icons8-file-check-48.png";
    private Scene scene;
    private Pane root;
    static  Stage stage;
    private String otDirPath = null;
    private ResourceBundle.Control control;
    private ResourceBundle bundle;
    private final Node iconDitaOtRoot;
    private final Node iconDitaOt;
    private final Node iconDitaOtPlugin;

    public OtMainController() throws MalformedURLException {
        ditaOtInfos = new DitaOtInfos();
        control = new XmlResourceBundleControl();
        URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File(RESOURCE_BUNDLE_PATH).toURI().toURL()});
        Locale locale=Locale.getDefault();
        bundle = XmlResourceBundle.getBundle("ditaOtAppProp", locale, urlLoader, control);
        iconDitaOtRoot = new ImageView(new File(ICON_FILE_PATH + File.separator + DITAOT_ROOT_ICON).toURI().toString() );
        iconDitaOt = new ImageView(new File(ICON_FILE_PATH + File.separator + DITAOT_ICON).toURI().toString() );
        iconDitaOtPlugin = new ImageView(new File(ICON_FILE_PATH + File.separator + DITAOT_PLUGIN_ICON).toURI().toString() );
        
    }
    
    @FXML
    private TreeView<TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree>> tvDitaOt;
    public void setScene(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }
    public void setRoot(Pane root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(java.net.URL url, java.util.ResourceBundle bundle) {
        TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot dataDitaOtRoot = new TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot(bundle.getString("tvTxtDitaOtRoot"));
        TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree> ditaOtTreeItemRoot = new TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree>(dataDitaOtRoot, iconDitaOtRoot);

        this.tvDitaOt.setRoot(ditaOtTreeItemRoot); // ここでコンパイルエラー
        this.tvDitaOt.setShowRoot(false);
    }
    
    public static void setStage(Stage stageParam) {
        stage = stageParam;
    }
    //...
}
```

#### 関連するクラス

TreeItemDataDitaOtTree.java

```
public abstract class TreeItemDataDitaOtTree {
    // Empty!
}
```

TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot.java

```
public class TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot extends TreeItemDataDitaOtTree{
    private final String rootTitle;
    
    public String getRootTitle() {
        return this.rootTitle;
    }

    public TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot(String rootTitle) {
        this.rootTitle = rootTitle;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return getRootTitle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました．

`setRoot` が

> The method setRoot(TreeItem<TreeItem>)  in the
> type TreeView<TreeItem>

のように解釈されるのはどうにもわかりません．

public final void setRoot​(TreeItem value)

のはずです．

https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#setRoot(javafx.scene.control.TreeItem)

解決法は、ただひたすらに `@SuppressWarnings` で逃げるのみでした．以下でコンパイルエラーは消えます．

```
    @FXML
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes"})
    private TreeView tvDitaOt;
```

```
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public void initialize(java.net.URL url, java.util.ResourceBundle bundle) {
        TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot dataDitaOtRoot = new TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot(bundle.getString("tvTxtDitaOtRoot"));
        TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree> ditaOtTreeItemRoot = new TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree>(dataDitaOtRoot, iconDitaOtRoot);
        this.tvDitaOt.setRoot(ditaOtTreeItemRoot);
        this.tvDitaOt.setShowRoot(false);
    }
```

この後でTreeViewを更新するコードを動かすと（まだボコボコではありますが）表示してくれました．なんとかこの先コーディングを進められそうです．

[image: TreeViewの表示]

お騒がせいたしました．

### 追記

違っていました．TreeViewの型パラメータの使い方をまったくわかっていませんでした．`@SuppressWarnings` は必要ありません．

```
    @FXML
    private TreeView<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree> tvDitaOt;
```

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(java.net.URL url, java.util.ResourceBundle bundle) {
        TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot dataDitaOtRoot = new TreeItemDataDitaOtRoot(bundle.getString("tvTxtDitaOtRoot"));
        TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree> ditaOtTreeItemRoot = new TreeItem<TreeItemDataDitaOtTree>(dataDitaOtRoot);

        this.tvDitaOt.setRoot(ditaOtTreeItemRoot);
        this.tvDitaOt.setShowRoot(false);
    }
```

が正解です．